# QR computation only in square matrix A?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I thought the following was true. But the answer is False.
Why so? Could anybody give me some counterexample?

For any matrix A, one can find Q and R such that A = QR
, where Q is an orthogonal matrix
and R is an upper triangular matrix with non-negative entries on the diagonal.

Comment: Where did you see it claimed to be false?

Comment: It depends what you mean by "upper triangular". Normally we relax the definition of upper triangular such that you can do $QR$ for "tall" matrices but usually not "wide" matrices.

Comment: Ah, yes, of course.

Comment: @ChristopherA.Wong I don't follow. While QR decomposition is usually defined for tall matrices, there is nothing preventing one from doing it for a wide matrix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any real square matrix $A$ may be decomposed as $A = QR$

where $Q$ is an orthogonal matrix and $R$ is an upper triangular matrix (also called right triangular matrix). This generalizes to a complex square matrix $A$ and a unitary matrix $Q$.

More generally, we can factor a complex $m\times n$ matrix $A$, with $m ≥ n$, as the product of an $m\times m$ unitary matrix $Q$ and an $m\times n$ upper triangular matrix $R$.

[for more detail follow this link](http://matpc41.ee.tut.fi/ML02/Matrix%20Algebra/Lecture%20Notes/chapter4.pdf)